# what register is returned when creating a procedure to add two XMM registers

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, avx, calling-convention

Im calling a ASM function on C++ and I want to be able to return the YMM2 stored value, I know that the register returned on a procedure is the RAX, how can I be able to return the YMM2 value and where I can store that value on C++.

```
.data
    vec1 real4 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0
    vec2 real4 9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0,16.0
    
.code

SumProc proc
    vmovups ymm0, ymmworld ptr [vec1]
    vmovups ymm1, ymmworld ptr [vec2]
    
    vaddps ymm2, ymm0,ymm1
    ret
```

Comment: Look at C compiler output for a function that returns `__m256`.  https://godbolt.org/z/hTjfTo5bf.  (spoiler alert: even the crappy Windows non-`vectorcall` convention returns in ymm0, unlike how it passes vector args to functions.  x86-64 System V always passes and returns in xmm/ymm registers)

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called [Application Binary Interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), which can differ per architecture and even per compiler. For example, the AMD64 ABI used everywhere except Windows states "Floating-point return values are similarly stored in XMM0 and XMM1.[25]:25 The wider YMM and ZMM registers are used for passing and returning wider values in place of XMM when they exist"

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking for is called [Application Binary Interface (ABI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), which can differ per architecture and even per compiler.

For example, the AMD64 ABI used everywhere except Windows states

> Floating-point return values are similarly stored in XMM0 and XMM1. The wider YMM and ZMM registers are used for passing and returning wider values in place of XMM when they exist.

The `__vectorcall` Windows calling convention mentioned in the comments is the same:

> Resulting vector type and HVA values are returned using the first four XMM/YMM registers

The default Windows return convention is not explicitly stated, so it is best to try it and see on godbolt.org.